# How do I use ElGamal encryption with ezPyCrypto

Tags: python, public-key-encryption, elgamal

I came across an nice encryption module [ezPyCrypto](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/ezPyCrypto/) for python's PyCrypto module. In the description it says that the user can specify between RSA and ElGamal encryption, but I can't figure out where I'm supposed to specify this in the code ([API here](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/ezPyCrypto/detail/index.html)).

Has anyone else managed this or have any experience with ezPyCytpo? Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Here's the description I was talking about:

Features:

1. ezPyCrypto lets you:

   - Generate, export and import public and private keys
   - Encrypt and decrypt strings with ease
   - Optionally create encrypted data as email-friendly text
   - Sign and verify strings (incl. documents)
   - Protect your private key with a passphrase
   - Create 'streams', for sending data through secured sockets
   - Choose any public key size you like (2048-bit recommended)
   - **Choose between RSA and ElGamal for public key,** and IDEA, DES3, Blowfish, ARC4, IDEA for session key
   - Rest in the comfort of security, with 256-bit session keys and defences against common               RSA and ElGamal attacks, which will painfully frustrate anyone seeking to violate your privacy.

Comment: If the documentation is any indication, it looks like the library is not complete.